# Hosting a ServerSocket on a specific IP Address

Tags: java, sockets, ip, multicast

I'm working on a project that is designed to be portable across random systems, and have a "server" type program hosted on one computer using `ServerSocket`, and another "client" program on another computer connecting to that "server" on the same network, using `socket`. I would like the client to always figure out where the server is on the network, without having to use a multicast system or a hosted system elsewhere, making it all local. I was under the impression that I am able to host the `ServerSocket` on a specific IP address, and I tried that here:

```
try {
    InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.859.672");
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(Integer.parseInt("9532"), 50, addr);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But that returns the error

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: 192.168.859.672
at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1293)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1246)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1162)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1098)
at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1048)
at com.pulsepanda.dragon.core.Connection.startServer(Connection.java:30)
at com.pulsepanda.dragon.core.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:25)
at com.pulsepanda.dragon.core.Run.main(Run.java:5)
```

If this is a way to have it work, having the `ServerSocket` hosted on a specific IP address, what am I doing wrong? If this is not a valid way of doing things, I have two questions: What is a way I can do this purely locally, without a multicast system, and 2) what is what I'm doing actually used for?

Thank you!

Comment: You can only bind a server socket to an IP address that's configured on the system you're running on.

Comment: By system, do you mean the network, or the host computer?

Comment: system = the computer your application executes on.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to use DNS. Each instance of the server can have the same unqualified hostname. The local DNS server translates that for you to whatever the IP address is for that server.

Comment: would that be portable with the program? for example, if i set it up on my system, finish the project, and then load it onto a different network, would it work the same? or does the DNS have to be set up per network

Answer (score 0):

If it is the UnknownHostException you want to get rid of, that would be by assigning a valid IP address. 
Example follows:

```
addr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.85.67");
```

See [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Inet4Address.html#format) for more information regarding the format.

Answer (score 0):

`192.168.859.672` is not a valid IP address. The elements have to be in the range 0..255.

The IP address has to be one that is local to the host the server is running on.

`Integer.parseInt("9532")` is just a pointlessly roundabout way of writing `9532`.

Comment: well, the reason i did that is the PORT is changed elsewhere, but for question sake i made it the numbers.

Comment: You seem to be carrying the port number around internally as a String. Should be an int. The place to convert strings to integers is at the point the string is first provided, so that you validate it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

change your host file
/etc/hosts

add following line

127.0.1.1   192.168.859.672